# which python3 returns global python binary not the virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

I have created a new virtual environment in freshly installed Ubuntu. Activating it doesn't return the python from the env python instead it returns the path of global bin python and pip.
I can access the venv binary using `./env/bin/python` but this doesn't seem convenient.
Is there any fix for that?
following is information about paths while running it in environment:

```
>> which python
/usr/bin/python
>> which pip
/usr/bin/pip
>> echo $PATH
/mnt/sdb2/Projects/env/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Does your mount go to a Windows filesystem?

Comment: No, It is on Linux.

Comment: I tried deleting the env folder and recreating it and it started working. But this doesn't seem the solution.

Comment: Show us 1) how you created the virtual environment, and 2) how you activated it.  3) Show us what is in the env's `bin` directory.

Comment: Have you (perchance) create the virtual environment for Python 3 rather Python 2?  (Note that "python" may be Python 2.7 on some versions of Ubuntu.  If it is, you can `apt install python-is-python3` if you want.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the name of the venv folder?
I had the same problem and reverting the folder name solved my issue.

Comment: This seems like a good answer, but the way its formulated it is better fitted as a comment on the original question. Another option is to improve it by adding additional instructions or a toy example to support future viewers in understanding the solution more easily.